# crontab get jobs of current user when run in a script via sudo

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I want to get all cronjobs like this:

```
crontab -l
```

However I execute this command insude a shell script that is called using sudo.

`crontab -l` therefore refers to the sudo entries instead of the cronjobs of the current user.

is there a way to specify the current user with `crontab -l` without hard coding the user name in the script?

Comment: @NullDev thanks. sudo crontab -u $(whoami) -l works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```sh
$(whoami)
```

for getting the current username.